# Add number to custom section in contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, numbering, chapters

Im using the \mybibliography environment but want to add it to my table of contents, it comes in fine but its just not numbered.

The code im using for that section is:

```
\newpage
\markboth{}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\begin{thebibliography} {8}
```

The output I get is

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
   Bibliography

The output im trying to get is where it follows the numbering.
such as:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
4. Bibliography

Its in a report format. If you need anymore info let me know sorry new to latex!

Comment: Are you really using `\begin{thebibliography}` etc. manually, i.e. not using `bibtex` or `biblatex`? In the later case you could use the means of the packages instead of manually adding the `References` to the ToC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Item 1}
\chapter{Item 2}
\chapter{Item 3}
\chapter{References}
\renewcommand\bibname{}
\begin{thebibliography} {8}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used book but report works the same way.

Comment: Yeah but at the moment all of the titles are numbered themselves whenever i use {chapter} but creating the bibliography sort of ruined me but i need it on the contents for my report

Comment: Hum, I am not sure that I understand what you want. Have you looked at my code? Why does it not fit your needs?

Comment: i tried that way before but it leaves a massive white space where the bibname is supposed to go? Thats why I didnt create a chapte for references in the hopes there was a way to add it to the contents

Comment: Quick and dirty: add negative vertical space `\vspace{-1cm}`

Comment: makes no difference where would i put it I've put it after beginning the bibliography but should it be somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry but the problem remains quite unclear to me. I cannot help further. You wanted a number item in the toc for the bibliography. You have this now. If there is a remaining problem, please show it to us, clearly.

Comment: ok no problem thankyou though! fixed the numbers! :)

Comment: @MitulSuchak: The proper way to say 'Thank you' is to accept an answer!